# How to choose a specific thread to run selected tasks in ThreadPoolExecutor in Java?

Tags: java, session, httprequest, httpresponse, threadpoolexecutor

My requirement is: I have a backend server to process the http request in different sessions. Each `session` might need several `http requests` and `responses` before it is terminated. Each `session` will cost one thread. I use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to manage the `thread`.

My problem is: when submit the tasks which is the http request, how can I let `ThreadPoolExecutor` to select a correct thread to handle the `tasks`? That means if the task is the first request for the session, the idle thread should be selected or new `thread` is created; if the `request` is not the first one, the `thread` handling previous `requests` in the same `session` should be selected.

Comment: you can use `PriorityQueue` in which request sould have a priority wise pick up for `threads` which are present in `threadpoolexecutor`

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct way to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Why do you need to reuse the same thread anyways? Most web systems use different threads per session, depending on which are available.

Answer (score 0):

Your request violates the basic premise of a thread *pool*, where all threads are equal and reused as they become available.

What you could do to meet your goal is submitting a "meta-task" to your pool, such which will usurp a thread and block it until the session is done. Within session state hold a reference to that meta-task and submit work into it. At the end of the session, end the task, which will then automatically release the underlying thread to the pool.

Comment: @Topolnik, you are right. The reason I want to keep one thread for one session is that in our current code implementation, every thread needs some cost to initialize and is related to the session state. The later request is depended on previous request. When the session is terminated, the thread is ended. So, I want to use the threadpoolexecutor to pool the threads even the session is terminated.

Comment: @Topolnik it does look to be the case what you stated about Java thread pool premise. However, the need to bind related tasks to the same thread is a real need sometimes. e.g. In an asynchronous contextual event process, the only way to guarantee processing related events in exactly the same order as they come in to the queue is to bind all those events to the same logical thread. I know specialized commercial products have native support of that. Wonder if there is some generic way: Selecting named thread from pool. If the target thread is busy, block/queue up until the thread is available.

Comment: @ric The thread-per-session model is a death sentence to your scalability. Typical sessions last for a long time and have great pauses between requests. 90% of the threads would be sitting idle and consuming a lot of system resources. However, I don't see any fundamental need why you would end up with this design; it's probably some library that expects to always run on the same thread.

Comment: @Topolnik It's not exactly a session concept - The same named thread can service unrelated events, but the same group of related events have to go to the same thread. It's a way of ensure sequential processing of events in the same related group. Sequencialness and Asynchronousness/scalability are fundamentally opposing forces we have to joggle at times. Opinions differ on how to ensure sequence, which is not the current question. I had simple enough (one class) wrapper to achieve named-thread summon and execute using JDK concurrent API, but was wondering alternatives to the home-grown setup.

Comment: @Topolnik To be clear, in my own way of summoning "named-thread" by its name, I am really naming a thread pool that has only a single thread in it, rather than naming the thread itself. So what you said about JDK thread pool premise still holds.